# How to import SQLite-DB with empty rows in C#?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, import

I'm reading data from a SQLite-DB in C# with LINQ. It works fine until there is an empty row in the SQLite-DB, then my tool crashes. Does anybody know how I can skip or "handle" an empty row (i.e. a row with just a PrimaryKey but NO FunctionId & Name).

This line crashes with "The specified cast is not valid".

```
List<Functions> Functions = (from f in context.Functions
                                    select f).ToList();
```

I even tried:

```
List<Functions> Functions = (from f in context.Functions
                                    select f).Where(x => x.FunctionId != null).ToList();
```

Model:

```
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int? PrimaryKey{ get; set; }

        [Column]
        public int? FunctionId{ get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

The errormessage I get is "The specified cast is not valid".
It looks like the problem is the empty FunctionId and I tried to make the FunctionId nullable, but still the same error happens.

**UPDATE:**
Ok the problem is .ToList()

If I write

```
IQueryable<Functions> Functions = (from f in context.Functions
                                    select f)
```

it works. Then I manually have to filter out the null values and convert it to a list.

Comment: You're saying your primary keys are also null?

Comment: If `FunctionId` is nullable column, you need to change type to `int?`

Comment: @BugFinder Primary Keys are fortunately not null
@ Darjan Bogdan yeah I tried that too, but still the same error message

Comment: thanks @safarondiss I was confused as you said the row was empty.. its not empty if it has a primary key